# How to connect a mobile device and install android application in that device?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

How can I connect to a mobile device and install android application in that device?

Comment: Can you clarify further?  Are you trying to connect an android phone and load an APK from Eclipse or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have android sdk installed on your machine. And then you can use the command adb -d install .apk

Answer (score 0):

You Just get your device connected via USB to your computer. Do ensure that what so ever Handset You are Using its USB drivers are installed over your computer.

After Your Device connected, right click on the project folder in the package explorer and select Run As -> Run Configuration -> 
Select Target Mannual radio button.

Then when you will run the program it will show you your device to select to deploy your app.